# babel-loader cacheDirectory unknown option

Tags: webpack, babeljs

When I enable cacheDirectory for babel-loader, I get the following error when running webpack:

> Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\Projects\xxx\index.js: Unknown option: base.{"presets":["react". Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more info

If I remove cacheDirectory, everything works fine. Does anyone know what I'm missong

My loader looks like this:

```
{ test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify(babelrc) + '&cacheDirectory', 'eslint'] }
```

My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
 "presets": [
  "react",
  "es2015",
  "stage-0"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing JSON style configuration and query string style configuration in you `babel-loader` config.

Try this:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: [
    'babel?' + JSON.stringify(
      Object.assign({}, babelrc, {cacheDirectory: true})
    ),
    'aslant
  ]
}
```

Also what's `babelrc` variable? I think if you have `.babelrc` in your package dir `babe-loader` will pick up it automatically.

Comment: the babelrc holds my .babelrc file as i don't have it in the root of my project but in a separate config directory. I bring it in like this var babelrc = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./App/config/.babelrc'));